# How to Count and Group Occurences in a 2-D Array?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, counter

I am attempting to parse a 2-D array of data in python similar to the following

```
[0,0]
[0,2]
[0,4]
[0,3]
[1,4]
[1,3]
[2,6]
[2,3]
[2,4]
[3,8]
```

By first counting the number of occurrences of the first column, then creating an array based on that and grouping things based on that to get, for example:

```
[0,0]
[0,2]
[0,4]
[0,3]
```

I am trying to do this using the following

```py
import numpy as np

Data = np.zeros(shape = (10,2))
Data = [[0,0],[0,2],[0,4],[0,3],[1,4],[1,3],[2,6],[2,3],[2,4],[3,8]]
print(Data)

for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,10):
        Count = 0
        if i == Data[j,0]:
            Count += 1
        return Count
        DataSet(i) = np.zeros(shape = (Count,2))
        DataSet[i,0] = Data[i,0]
        DataSet[i,1] = Data[i,1]
    print(DataSet[i])
```

I have been getting errors with getting an iterative count, as well as filling the arrays created. How can I improve this code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: what is the expected output ? I think you will benefit from using pandas library.

Comment: I would like to create a different array for each value in the first column, so nx2 where n is the number of occurrences, then fill that array with the corresponding data.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Why are you seemingly mixing NumPy arrays and Python lists? What is that `return Count` doing in the middle of a loop, outside of a function? This looks like a toy example, can you show us your actual program? You don't even really explain what the code is meant to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to reiterate the question, you need to create an array that holds all the numbers of the second column that have the same number in the first column.
In my answer, the program creates a new array to hold the numbers. to retrieve the numbers that all share a 0 in the first column you would call:

```
new_data[0]
```

This is the code I created to hopefully answer your question:

```
Data = [[0,0],[0,2],[0,4],[0,3],[1,4],[1,3],[2,6],[2,3],[2,4],[3,8]]
new_data = []


for i in range(0,4):
    count = 0
    for j in range(0,10):
        if(i == Data[j][0]):
            count += 1
            if(count == 1):
                new_data.append([])
            new_data[i].append(Data[j][1])

print(new_data)
```

Hope this helps!